# Overcoming Magento’s WYSIWYG Few Tags Disappear

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

This option allows you to set a rule for empty elements being valid.Default settings will currently remove these empty elements from the code after you save. Example:

Solution

Step1 : Go to js folder in root of your magento installation

js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

Step2 :

Once you have this file open do a search for “var settings = {“. then add following line

extended_valid_elements: '+a[*],+span[*]',

+a[*] is example but you use any html element that disappearing after save.

Comment: Why have you put same content in question and answer both?

Answer (score 0):

This option allows you to set a rule for empty elements being valid.Default settings will currently remove these empty elements from the code after you save. Example:

Solution

Step1 : Go to js folder in root of your magento installation

js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

Step2 :

Once you have this file open do a search for “var settings = {“. then add following line

extended_valid_elements: '+a[*],+span[*]',

+a[*] is example but you use any html element that disappearing after save.